# Завершить процесс в определенное время bash

Tags: linux, bash, cron

Здравствуйте!

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать скрипт для "убийства" процесса каждый день в 04:30.

**P.S.:** ОС CentOS. Знаю про `cron`, `bash` не изучал. Процесс называется `/root/samp03/samp03svr`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Используйте для этого крон в сочетании с командой `pkill samp03svr`.

Соответственно строка для `/etc/crontab`:

```
30 4 * * * pkill samp03svr
```

Answer (score 3):

Сейчас придут настоящие админы и скажут как правильно, но я бы делал через cron: killall samp03svr